# How do I make a textbox read only using code when an event happens in VB?

Tags: vb.net

I've made a program in VB where the user selects from a drop down box whether they would like to find out speed, distance or time. There are three textboxes on the form where the user can enter speed, distance and time, and they don't enter anything for the one which they want to find out.

When the user chooses to find out speed, I want the speed textbox to be changed to read only, when the user chooses to find out distance, I want that textbox to be changed to read only, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a Textbox read only by using the following code:

`textbox1.ReadOnly = true`

You can also found out more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983585(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: Wrong link... Woops.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event and set the `Enabled` property in there.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Me.TextBoxSpeed.Enabled = ComboBox1.SelectedItem <> "Speed"
    Me.TextBoxTime.Enabled = ComboBox1.SelectedItem <> "Time"
    Me.TextBoxDistance.Enabled = ComboBox1.SelectedItem <> "Distance"
End Sub
```